# How to remove text like <%@ include view="MirrorPage" %> with jSoup

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, coldfusion-9, cfml

I am pulling html email content from a database.  The html contains strings like :

```
<%@ include view="MirrorPage" %> and <%= stagingArea.techField.label %>
```

that I would like to remove before displaying.

I'm using Coldfusion 9 and jSoup to parse the html.  jSoup worked great removing <script> content that was in the html.

```
<cfset emailHTML=jsoup.parse(detail["html"]) />
<cfset emailHTML.select("script").remove() />
```

I just unclear on how to select <% with jSoup since it isn't a true "tag".

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use jSoup to parse HTML which contains `<%@ ... %>` it gets converted to `&lt;%@ ... %&gt;` and is treated as text.

Since it is simple text, there's no way for jSoup to pick it up, or treat it any different to other text.

Assuming these markers are placeholders/tokens that follow simple rules (i.e. there's no nesting, they wont contain '%' outside of their markers, etc), you can remove them with a regex like this:

```
<cfset emailHTML = rereplace( emailHTML.html() ,'&lt;%[@=][^%]+%&gt;','','all') />
```

(You may or not want to then use `jsoup.parse(emailHTML)` to get the string back into an object again.)

Of course, if these placeholders are there for a reason, you may need to do something more complex than simply removing them - and if they might be including HTML then you need to consider if they should be processed *before* jSoup is invoked to remove script tags/etc.

Comment: Thanks Peter,  After thinking more about this, I thought that regex would be the better tool for removing these strings.  In the email application they are used for generating the content.  I am pulling the html out of the database for display purposes only so they aren't needed.

Comment: Sometimes the hardest thing about regex is working out if it's the right tool or not. :)
Might still  be worthwhile replacing with a non-blank string (e.g. `...`) - in case there end up being display differences due to something like an empty td - depends who the audience is I guess.